# Safe way to get ProcessID using Named Pipes

Tags: c#, wcf, named-pipes

I have an application that consist of a GUI and a service. These are running on the same machine and communicates over Named Pipes via WCF.

From the service I'm trying to get the Process ID of the process calling into the service over the Named Pipe. However, I'm having a very hard time doing this when using WCF.

I've created a test application that allows me to do this using Named Pipes without WCF (directly via System.IO.Pipes) - but the only way I can figure out how to do this, requires me to use SafePipeHandle.DangerousGetHandle().

I'm wondering if anyone can give me some pointers on

- Can the PID be fetched using WCF or by not using the DangerousGetHandle()?
- Will it be alright using the SafePipeHandle.DangerousGetHandle() method? (It doesn't sound safe)

I really don't want to send the PID as meta data or as part of the message from the GUI, as this could easily be spoofed.

My sample server code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
using (var server = new NamedPipeServerStream("TestPipe", PipeDirection.InOut, NamedPipeServerStream.MaxAllowedServerInstances, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Server waiting for connection...");
    server.WaitForConnection();

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(server))
    {
        string message;
        while ((message = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            uint clientProcessId;
            if (NativeMethods.GetNamedPipeClientProcessId(server.SafePipeHandle.DangerousGetHandle(), out clientProcessId))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Received: {message} from PID {clientProcessId}");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to get client process ID.");
            }
        }
    }

    server.Disconnect();
}
Console.WriteLine("Server disconnected...");
```

}

The NativeMethods is just a wrapper:

```
public static class NativeMethods
{
   [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
   public static extern bool GetNamedPipeClientProcessId(IntPtr Pipe, out uint ClientProcessId);
}
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. I've run completely out of ideas :)

Comment: I think you can use **NetNamedPipeBinding** to determine the **pid**. This post can help you [WCF NetNamedPipeBinding Determine Process ID Of Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33574222/wcf-netnamedpipebinding-determine-process-id-of-client)

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that the handle of the pipe will remain valid while the server is still connected to the pipe and so this is a safe use of the unsafe-in-general method.

The risks that are warned about are for handles that were marked as invalid/reused but I don't think that would be at all likely with your code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.dangerousgethandle

Comment: I'm a bit worried about this formulation from the documentation: "For example, an untrusted caller can query data on the handle just returned and receive information for an entirely unrelated resource."
If I validate the ProcessID of the client (by e.g. validating the process signature or similar) as the first thing on the server when a request comes in, would that make me safe from this?

Comment: I don't think the handle of the pipe will get invalidated until the server.Disconnect() line.

The code gets the SafeHandle from the pipe and immediately uses the underlying handle so I don't think it's possible that windows would have reused it while this is going on. It would be dangerous to store that handle and use it at a later time.